# Prevent two way sync from going on an infinite loop

Tags: ruby, postgresql, synchronization

I am working on two way sync between two databases, something like what `cloudconnect.com` did. I am using DB triggers to send data back and forth between the DB's. I was wondering whether I could prevent the PG database in the local from calling the update trigger when the update is done from the remote DB (preventing continuous looping).

I tried using `SET session_replication_role: 'replica'`, which worked, but this will also violate the database integrity by disabling the column constrains.

I was then thinking to have a extra field called `disable_trigger` and set it to true in the query in which I want the trigger to not happen. But I don't want to change the schema of the database.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent Slony? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/different-replication-solutions.html

Comment: Not only that, this sounds like you're reinventing master-master replication. Why?

Comment: Basically, the remote DB that I was talking about is the salesforce API. The local one is postgres.

Comment: DIY is unwise here. Use one of the established solutions like Slony-I or Bucardo. (BTW, future PostgreSQL versions may support this natively; see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide)

Comment: See also a slightly later post by user ID closely associated with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20970221/398670